# Nested regex replacement in a loop with Pandas

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I am trying to conduct nested regex replacement in pandas and I am having hard time capturing all nested components in regex.

For example, I would like to remove all instances of `'ba'` and `'ba ca'` from column `A` in dataframe. But I am able to remove only `'ba'` while `'ca'` part of `"ba ca"` is not being removed because I think `'ba'` is nested within `'ba ca'`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['ba t', 'ba ca t', 'foo', 'ba it'],'B': ['abc','abc', 'bar', 'xyz']})

replace_list=['ba','ba ca']

for i in replace_list:
    df=df.replace({'A': r'^({})'.format(i)}, {'A': ''}, regex=True)
df
```

I would expect row `index=1` for column `A` to be `t` and not `ca t`.  Any help is highly appreciated.

```
       A    B
0      t  abc
1   ca t  abc
2    foo  bar
3     it  xyz
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the `replace_list` into a single regex:

```
df['A'].str.replace('|'.join(replace_list[::-1]), '').str.strip()
```

Output:

```
0      t
1      t
2    foo
3     it
Name: A, dtype: object
```

Note the reversed `replace_list`, so that it first checks `ba ca` and then `ba`, thus not leaving the `ca` part.

Comment: The "it first checks ba ca and then ba, thus not leaving the ca part." should have come first.

Comment: Thank you, I tried below code and I am getting the same wrong result.  What am I missing?  df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['ba t', 'ba ca t', 'foo', 'ba it'],'B': ['abc','abc', 'bar', 'xyz']})
replace_list=['ba ca','ba']
df['A'].str.replace('|'.join(replace_list[::-1]), '').str.strip()

Comment: @cs95 Are you suggesting that I should move the _note_ part to the top of the answer?

Comment: You can have your replace list in descending order of their respective string lengths. That will check the 'ba ca' first and then 'ba' as stated in the above answer. And it will definitely work well if you have more items in your replace list.

Comment: @Nora Change `replace_list[::-1]` to `replace_list`, since the `ba ca` comes first now. reversing the list is unnecessary :)

Comment: It is still leaving ca part